# Get and push data from netsuite using python

Tags: python, rest, wsdl, netsuite

I have a task in which I have to fetch data and push data in netsuite using python script and wsdl together.

Any kind of help in form of sample script or study links would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use restlets for this purpose. once you create that you can access it using python. Here is a sample code i found from the netsuite help.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import requests
import time

url = "https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=992&deploy=1"
token = oauth.Token(key="080eefeb395df81902e18305540a97b5b3524b251772adf769f06e6f0d9dfde5", secret="451f28d17127a3dd427898c6b75546d30b5bd8c8d7e73e23028c497221196ae2")
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="504ee7703e1871f22180441563ad9f01f3f18d67ecda580b0fae764ed7c4fd38", secret="b36d202caf62f889fbd8c306e633a5a1105c3767ba8fc15f2c8246c5f11e500c")

http_method = "GET"  
realm="ACCT123456"

params = {
    'oauth_version': "1.0",
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'oauth_token': token.key,
    'oauth_consumer_key': consumer.key
}

req = oauth.Request(method=http_method, url=url, parameters=params)
signature_method = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
header = req.to_header(realm)
headery = header['Authorization'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
headerx = {"Authorization": headery, "Content-Type":"application/json"}
print(headerx)
conn = requests.get("https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=992&deploy=1",headers=headerx)
print(conn.text)
```

Comment: @Jauhar Thanks for your answer. I have been asked to do the task using wsdl. Can you provide any help on that?

Comment: Where would one get the token and consumer key for your restlet?